# Thinking of adding request button on site for items not available? Good idea or Facebook like button will do?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, facebook

Thinking of adding Request Button for items not available on a planned site. Is this a good idea or will Facebook Like button do to express a"want this item" message?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have an eCommerce site; you want to know what to do if you don't have a product available - a) allow the user to press 'request', or b) allow the user to 'Like' you on Facebook? What has Liking you got to do with having products unavailable?

Comment: Seconded, please add more detail.

Comment: You got a) right but b) would mean writing the message that makes sense for people to click on Facebook like button. It could be written this way--"Press Like if you want this item"? People then press Like button using Facebook. It's unconventional and I don't see it anywhere else.

Comment: Can you explain why you think 'Like' *would* be a good option here? Because it makes no sense to me. People press 'like' because they like something. I don't imagine they like an item being out of stock.

Comment: Jon, I had doubts about its effectiveness, because of its inherent purpose--to like something-- and you just cleared it up. Thanks. If only there was a more effective way of requesting something. I've heard Request is too soft but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also, wanting a product doesn't necessarily mean I want to let some unknown subset of my facebook friends know that I want it...

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add request button explicitly.**

**Purpose**

People around the world are used to like buttons , not just from Facebook but in many other websites. Like buttons as world knows it has a different purpose. Using a like button to request an item that is not available is not something that user will expect. It is far from obvious.

On the other hand you can add a text box for email id and a button next to it which says `notify me` in which case the purpose is obvious. This will appear beneath the out of stock (or whatever text you are using to let the user know that you don't have the item).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook 'Like' button is not appropriate for requesting items on your site that are not available because the intention of the user is not liking the item but wanting to request that product. Like doesn't mean they want to buy it.

I would suggest solutions where you encourage the user to take action by providing more details. It's a win-win scenario. You know exactly what the item request is and who requests that item.

Option 1: For those items that are **Out of Stock or Not Available** for example, you may want to add a section where if the person wants to buy that item, they'll be notified via email.

[image]

Option 2: If the person is searching for an item that is not available in your site, then let them request for that item by letting them fill up what the item is and get their email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modcloth.com has a feature where if an item sells out, they add a little button below the item that says "I Want It!" That way, they can gauge the demand for an item, and restock if it's high. They also have an option to add your email address, so you can be notified once it's back in stock.

I think you're worried that simply using "Request" is too bland, and you may be right. Try using stronger language, like "I Want It!", "Bring It Back!" or "Gotta Have It!" to spur people to use it. Offer them the option to know when it's returned.

As JonW said, "Like" makes no sense here. Someone can like an item, then forget all about it. If they really want it to the point of wanting to buy it, use language that will help convey that to a potential customer.